# Should I use Full Overlay or Half Overlay hinges?

Tags: hinges, door

I want to install two doors on this cabinet using European (concealed) hinges. They will be installed on a Frameless structure made of 18mm panels on the outside and a 27mm panel on the inside that is shared by one door and on the other side by drawers (see diagrams).

I understand that if two doors share the same panel, they use Half Overlay hinges (as per Rocker website). However, in this case, the door will not be sharing the interior panel. On the other side, there are shelves (in this case) and drawers in another case. Furthermore, the interior panel is thicker (27mm vs 18mm) than the exterior panel.

Should I still use half overlay hinges? Or use Full overlay as the door on the outside?

Hope the diagrams explain.

Thanks,

[image: Diagram]

[image: Cabinet]

See [this](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1540/what-is-the-difference-between-full-overlay-and-half-overlay-hinges) question for a description of the difference between full and half overlay hinges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the drawer overlay on the 27mm panel?  If it is more than 9mm you will have to use half-overlay hinges (as you won't have the 18mm needed for a full overlay.)

Comment: Hi, I will limit the drawer to 9mm. My understanding is that I will then use a Full Overlay hinge so that it takes up the full 18mm space (or 0mm clearance) and this will limit my drawer to 9mm as you said.